# Is there a `ifWindowCount` function in xmonad?

Tags: xmonad, xmonad-contrib

I am trying to find a function, that allows me to switch between XMonad-Layouts automatically depending on the amount of windows on the screen.

I have experienced similar behavior with the [ifWider](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Layout-PerScreen.html) function, which does the same depending on the screen width.
I doubt that there is a function for that in xmonad-contrib, so should I implement it myself? And how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used it but [XMonad.Layout.IfMax](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Layout-IfMax.html) looks like doing exactly that. You provide a number of windows and two layouts, and it will run one layout if up to that number of windows are present, and the other one otherwise.

```hs
import XMonad.Layout.IfMax

myLayoutHook = IfMax 2 Full (Tall ...) ||| ...
```